# How to handle the application with an alert when it crashed with out terminating the application in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, exception

I am getting an application as I selected the image from the photo library which of 696 kb at that time I am getting level 1 and level 2 warnings and application is terminated because of the crash.The Crash I got is

Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

For this I want to handle this crash with out terminating the app and to show it with an alert.

Any Suggestion's??

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your crash is likely due to the system killing your app because it exceeded its memory quota. The message you are reporting about Data Formatters is from the debugger, and does not say much.

What you should do is define your `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method and try to recover as much memory as possible when your get the warning. Take a look at this [S.O. topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430728/how-to-implement-didreceivememorywarning) for some hints and of course read [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) about it (Memory Management section).

Also inspect your app for memory leaks and improper memory usage patterns, like over-retaining.

There is not much you can do if iOS kills your app because of excessive memory usage. Anyway, you could display an alert in didReceiveMemoryWarning, so the user is warned that the app might crash any time soon (but you will show it several times before actually crashing).

Comment: Telling your user that the app is low on memory and may crash anytime is a terrible idea. What can he do about it? It's up to the developer to handle low memory warnings, not warn the user that something bad is going to happen.

Comment: What can he do about it? What about deleting user pictures that are too big for the device to manage or display in some way? What about suggesting the user to do something so that the *current status* is saved, if he wants, so that in case anything goes bad at least he can recover from there? You don't need to say: "hey, I am going to crash"! What do you know about all the apps that could be around there? It's up to human intelligence to understand how something can be used properly or not properly. There no obligation to do the wrong thing only because it is possible.