# iphone app working on most devices but not a few

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have recently been rewriting some of my iphone app because a couple of users have said it was crashing on certain events.

The event in question is when I add a new XIB to the view using the following code

```
AddItemViewController * add_item = [[AddItemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddItem" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self presentModalViewController:add_item animated:YES];

[add_item setViewFormat:2];
[add_item release];
```

it works perfectly on my iphone and a mate's ipod touch (both running 3.1.3) but another user on an ipod touch also with 3.1.3 says it crashes when the function above is called. Why could this be happening? Surely if it works on one device it should work on another?! Is there a better way to add a view which maybe doesnt crash?

I have also disabled all the code on the loading xib - so it literally is loading a near blank page.

It's SO annoying!! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that you handle memory warnings correctly? Ie see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491075/iphone-development-simulate-memory-warning) stackoverflow question. See also the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW49) about handling low-memory warnings.

Comment: that's a good point... I'll check it out! Don't actually think I manage it terribly well.