# Apple claim for app crash but I can't figure it out

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

Apple claims that my app crashes at launch, but I can't see where. On my iPhone and iPad it runs perfectly. This is the crash log, please help me to inspect what seems to be the problem.

Apple notes:

> We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5 and iPad running iOS 6.1.3, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> App crashes upon launch on iPhone 5 and iPad running iOS 6.1.3. Review was conducted using multiple iPhone 5 and iPad devices, but the result was the same.

[Crash log](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/e3/d9/62/e3d962bf-3f5b-f604-20af-1238e9f17510/temp..yamyuwng.crash):

```
Incident Identifier: A054AD54-C009-416E-B6EE-0EC7BA01C643
CrashReporter Key:   fbcc902d2921b94c746024ab49f67df0ffaed5e9
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:         LogoQuizOrig [2532]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/440F4F2C-12A2-4071-92E5-C061CDD2B64E/LogoQuizOrig.app/LogoQuizOrig
Identifier:      LogoQuizOrig
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-03-25 13:49:11.916 -0700
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x317443e2 0x3943f95e 0x314d2308 0x41218 0x41024 0x433fa 0x43074 0x3963a01e 0x42f48 0x42edc 0x41332 0x40a70 0x4073c 0x335b3a9c 0x335b3620 0x335ab82e 0x33553d1a 0x335537a8 0x335531ea 0x3526b5f2 0x3526b222 0x317193e2 0x31719386 0x3171820a 0x3168b238 0x3168b0c4 0x335aa468 0x335a72b4 0x3fde6 0x3fd9c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39933350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x398a9fb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x398e6366 abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e8edda abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e8c094 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3943fa58 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e8c118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e8c1b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x38e8d626 __cxa_rethrow + 90
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3943f9b0 objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3168b29c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3168b0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  UIKit                           0x335aa468 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
13  UIKit                           0x335a72b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  LogoQuizOrig                    0x0003fde6 0x3d000 + 11750
15  LogoQuizOrig                    0x0003fd9c 0x3d000 + 11676

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39933d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39881ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x398817f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39881680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x399235d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3985ed22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3985a374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39933d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39881ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x398817f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39881680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39922e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39922fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x317192b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3171802c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3168b238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3168b0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x37693390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3988c0de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3988bfa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3b3f5524
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3b3f5b78      r6: 0x1fd2ae64      r7: 0x2fdc3a14
    r8: 0x1fd2ae40    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x0000000c     r11: 0x1fd29610
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdc3a08      lr: 0x398a9fb7      pc: 0x39933350
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: Please post the **relevant portions** of the log here in your question. Expecting people to leave this site to even figure out what you're asking isn't very considerate, and without that information your question is meaningless to others in the future. (If the link expires, your question is too vague and without content that it will not be useful to others in the future.) Questions here should contain enough information to be understood and to be useful in future searches. There's an example of posting a question about a crash [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7885682/62576) for reference.

Comment: Please read this answer and try debugging it yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7814929/1698887

Comment: Looks like your code threw an exception.  You're going to need to figure out where by using the backtrace.

Comment: Drag the crash report into the Xcode organizer to get it symbolicated. Then you'll see the actual stack trace where the exception occurred.

Comment: I will paste the relevant code here. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, tested in several devices (iPhone/iPad/iPod touch) and still can't reproduce the error. This link makes me think maybe is not a problem with the code, but with review process : [Universal iPad App rejected because of launch crash that I can't reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770031/universal-ipad-app-rejected-because-of-launch-crash-that-i-cant-reproduce?rq=1)

Comment: When Apple is giving you a crash report, and your app is clearly shown in the stack traces and binary images, there definitely is **NO** problem with the review process but with your app! If you can't reproduce it, you simply can't create the same situation yet.

Comment: @Kerni Could be, you must be right. But what do you think about this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770031/universal-ipad-app-rejected-because-of-launch-crash-that-i-cant-reproduce?rq=1

Comment: Just to let you know, after more than a week working with Apple technical support, they finally approved the app without any modification on the code. On their words: "the error was only happening on one device. We believe it had a corrupted install of iOS or a damaged device"